# Safe to open file in text editor while writing to it in Python?

Tags: python, file, io

I have a long measurement being written to a text file using Python. Is it safe to open the file in Notepad while my script is running?

Comment: I dont think so

Comment: it depends on if the program locks the file- if you're on windows, notepad is *probably* ok. One alternative option could be to copy the file, and open the copy.

Comment: This may depend on your OS, your editor, and your actions. If you OS doesn't do something funny with locking files and you and your editor do not perform any writes, truncates or such, you should be fine.

Comment: I would avoid doing so unless you are sure that your file is opened in read only mode by the text editor (e.g.: vim -RM, on linux).

Comment: Without the OS and specific editor being included in the question, this isn't knowable. This often *is* safe, but we can't speak for every editor out there on every OS.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice seems to be: Copy file and open the copy.

Thanks @pault.

Comment: Why do you think this is the best practice?

Comment: Don't have to worry about whether the editor truncates or how to use it in read-only mode.

Comment: Why would an editor *ever* truncate a file that it's opening, when not explicitly told to save it? I've never heard of an editor doing such a thing -- though granted, I'm old-school enough to stick with `vim` and `emacs` (both of which are quite well-behaved).

Comment: Keep in mind that people open system logs in text editors *all the time*, and those logs are being continuously appended to by their very nature.

Comment: I don't know, but someone suggested it might happen in the comments.

Comment: Sure, but here's the thing -- if you ask "is it safe to assume that no editor will ever do X?" without specifying a specific editor, then we have to assume that Joe Bob's Weirdo Half-Assed Editor exists and will automatically try to change your file into a different characterset or something on startup, so you get (in your comments) an extremely conservative answer. In almost all cases, though, that answer is *unnecessarily* conservative.

Comment: (We also need to worry about editors on Windows in the case where no details are specified in the question, and Windows has much more restrictive file-locking rules by default than the Unix world does; opening a file even in read-only mode can restrict concurrent writes on Windows, whereas it has no effect on Unixlikes).